# samsung galaxy s8 camera capture image blurry

Tags: android, android-camera

I send the phone to the camera like this

```
Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        Intent pickIntent = new Intent();
        pickIntent.setType("image/*");
        pickIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        // we will handle the returned data in onActivityResult
        String pickTitle = "Select or take a new Picture"; 
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, pickTitle);
        chooserIntent.putExtra
                (
                        Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                        new Intent[]{captureIntent}
                );
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "This device doesn't support the crop action!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and the camera loads up fine with a clear image, but when I take the picture the confirm image screen is blurred like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8jKa.jpg)
When I take a picture outside of my app with just the camera app, the confirm screen looks fine. As far as I can tell with my few test devices this effects only the s8. Anyone else face this issue and/or know a fix or workaround?

Comment: There is no "workaround", insofar as this is not a programming issue with respect to your app. If you do not like Samsung's camera app, install somebody else's camera app. You are delegating to a third-party camera app, after all, and so the behavior of that app will vary widely among the thousands of Android device models.

Comment: The samsung camera app works fine when I use it independently of my app. And it looks like Instagram leverages the samsung camera app similarly and it seems to work there. Could anything in my code be effecting it? If so how? I can't thing of any way it would so don't really have a starting point on where to look.

Comment: "Could anything in my code be effecting it?" -- I can't see what. The only thing a bit odd is that you are not using `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to specify where you want the photo. Presumably, you are using the thumbnail via the `"data"` extra. Perhaps Samsung is doing something silly and having the confirmation screen use the thumbnail, just zoomed up or something.

Comment: It was because I was not using EXTRA_OUTPUT. Apparently it creates a very small file by default if I do not give it one. Thank you so much for your help.